# Closed form of $ \int_{-1}^{1} \operatorname{erf}(x)^n \,dx $ for $ n$ is positive even integer

Tags: integration, closed-form, orthogonality, error-function

I have checked [this paper](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/73b/jresv73bn1p1_a1b.pdf) titled "A Table of Integrals of the Error Functions" but I can't evaluate:$$\int \operatorname{erf}(x)^n \,dx$$ when $n$ is a positive integer.  What I really want to evaluate is the definite integral:$$\int_{-1}^1 \operatorname{erf}(x)^n \,dx $$ when $n$ is even integer because the integrand is an odd function for odd $n$, while for $n=2$ it has a nice closed form as shown here in [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(+erf(x)%5E2)),+x%3D-1+to+1).  Now my question here is:

> **Question:**
>   What is the closed form of: $\int_{-1}^{1} \operatorname{erf}(x)^n \,dx $, when $ n$ is a positive even integer ?

Comment: What makes you think there is a closed form?

Comment: what let me to feel that the existence of it for n=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am skeptical about a possible closed  form but, looking [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1172474/erf-squared-approximation), you will notice that there are quite good approximations
$$\left(\text{erf}(x)\right)^2\approx 1-e^{-a x^2}\qquad \text{with}\qquad  a=(1+\pi )^{2/3} \log ^2(2)$$

So, you can approximate
$$I_n=\int_{-1}^1 \left(\text{erf}(x)\right)^{2n}\,dx$$by 
$$J_n=\int_{-1}^1 \left(1-e^{-a x^2}\right)^{n}\,dx$$ for which the binomial expansion would be required (easy).

This would give you things like
$$J_1=2-\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}$$
$$J_2=2-\frac{2 \sqrt{\pi }
   \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}
   \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}$$
$$J_3=2-\frac{3 \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{a}\right)}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{3
   \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{2a}
   \right)}{\sqrt{a}}-\frac{\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{3}} \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{3a}
   \right)}{\sqrt{a}}$$
$$\color{blue}{J_n=2+\sqrt{\frac \pi a}\,\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{\sqrt{k}}\,\text{erf}\left(\sqrt{ak} \right) }\tag 1$$ I produce below a short table for comparison
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 0.591506 & 0.596751 \\
 2 & 0.279674 & 0.283168 \\
 3 & 0.151067 & 0.153256 \\
 4 & 0.0870954 & 0.0884650 \\
 5 & 0.0522216 & 0.0530855 \\
 6 & 0.0321485 & 0.0326982 \\
 7 & 0.0201718 & 0.0205243 \\
 8 & 0.0128409 & 0.0130686 \\
 9 & 0.00826756 & 0.00841548 \\
 10 & 0.00537202 & 0.00546863
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Update**

After my answer to your [next question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803363/behavior-of-int-11x2k-operatornameerfxk-dx/2806155#2806155), I reused for this problem my approach with the same Padé approximants and obtained as approximations
$$I_n=\frac 2{2n+1} \left(\frac{4}{\pi }\right)^n\,\, _2F_1\left(2 n,\frac{2n+1}{2};\frac{2n+3}{2};-\frac{1}{3}\right)\tag 2$$
$$I_n=\frac 2{2n+1} \left(\frac{4}{\pi }\right)^n\,F_1\left(\frac{2n+1}{2};-2 n,2 n;\frac{2n+3}{2};\frac{1}{30},-\frac{3}{10}\right)\tag 3$$

Comment: Thanks , by this way we can find J_n

Comment: @zeraouliarafik. At least an approximation of it.

Comment: Really it is a nice approximation , I should accept this slick answer

Comment: Since this question answered by good approximation, Could you answer me this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2803363/156150   and thanks

Comment: @zeraouliarafik. Since we are concerned by the $[-1,1]$ range, it would better to use $a=1.252309$.